# Javascript looping through variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, for-loop

So right now this is my current code and I'm trying to figure out a way to loop through the variables I've already declared (Assuming variables 1-9 already have values). I just wanted to know whether this was possible at all?

```
var title;
var brief;
var hover;
var whatTitle;
var whatDesc;
var whyTitle;
var whyDesc;
var funTitle;
var funDesc;
var titles = [];
var briefs = [];
var hovers = [];
var whatTitles = [];
var whatDescs = [];
var whyTitles = [];
var whyDescs = [];
var funTitles = [];
var funDescs = [];

    var obj = {'titles' : title};
    if(localStorage.getItem('titles') != null) {
        var tmp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('titles'));
        for(var i = 0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
            titles.push(tmp[i]);
        }

    }
    titles.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
```

Output I want if we printed out the looped code:

```
var obj = {'titles' : title};
    if(localStorage.getItem('titles') != null) {
        var tmp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('titles'));
        for(var i = 0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
            titles.push(tmp[i]);
        }

    }
    titles.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));

var obj = {'briefs' : brief};
    if(localStorage.getItem('briefs') != null) {
        var tmp1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('briefs'));
        for(var i = 0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
            briefs.push(tmp[i]);
        }

    }
    briefs.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem("briefs", JSON.stringify(briefs));

var obj = {'hovers' : hover};
    if(localStorage.getItem('hovers') != null) {
        var tmp2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hovers'));
        for(var i = 0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
            hovers.push(tmp[i]);
        }

    }
    hovers.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem("hovers", JSON.stringify(hovers));

...etc
```

Comment: To do that you need to declare ``Object`` or ``Array`` with this variables. Then it would be possible to loop over it. It is not possible to loop over variables, you need some data structure to loop over

Comment: Ahh, I see, but that means that in the Object/Array I would have to redeclare the variables from line 1-9 in my question so it would be var data = { 'title' : document.getElementById('element').value, etc..}  ?

Answer (score 3):

If the code is running in a browser, then you can do something like:

```
for(key in window) { console.log(window[key]) } // print all variables
```

The variables are associated to the global namespace. That is to say the upmost "this" reference or the window object.

Comment: This will give **all** keys on `window`, not just the ones he declared!

Comment: What @webNeat said. You CAN do this but you really shouldn't.

Comment: Well.. this is just one part of the javascript code and I have many other things on window as well so it may work but what @webNeat said, it would give me all the keys on the window. But thank you still!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there with the code you have. If you look at your "desired output" examples, you'll see that the only thing that really differs between each element of your "unrolled loop" is the key for local storage ('titles', 'briefs', 'hovers').

With that in mind, you could use an Object to map the keys to the variables you have at the top level. So this:

```
var titles = [];
var briefs = [];
var hovers = [];
var whatTitles = [];
var whatDescs = [];
...
```

Becomes (**UPDATE**: with the initializer values preserved):

```
var key_to_collection = {
  'titles': [title],
  'briefs': [brief],
  'hovers': [hovers],
  'whatTitles': [whatTitles],
  'whatDescs': [whatDescs],
}
```

Then, you loop over the values of this object:

```
Object.keys(key_to_collection).forEach(function(key) {
  var obj = {};
  collection = key_to_collection[key];
  obj[key] = collection;
  if(localStorage.getItem(key) != null) {
    var tmp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    for(var i = 0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
      collection.push(tmp[i]);
    }
  }
  collection.push(obj);
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(collection));
});
```

Comment: But what about the declared variables that have values in them? Variables 1-9 in my question^

Comment: Are you trying to pre-seed collections with those values? If so instead of using `titles: []` you can use `titles: [ title ]`. Your example is a little vague because title is null

Comment: @Marie by values I meant my variables from lines 1-9 in my question they have values in them already taken from my HTML code, for eg. var title = document.getElementById('elementID').value;

Comment: Is the value just a string? do you parse it? You can still do the same thing either way as long as you dont mind it coming first. And if you want it last you can use `shift` instead of `push`

Comment: @Marie yup, it's just a string and I don't think I've parsed it yet

Comment: I've updated the answer with @Marie's suggestion, which is correct.

Comment: There is something a bit off and I dont know if it was the OP example or your code audiodude. I was making an assumption about the data. @Kovi Based on your example the `title` array will contain an `object` that contains a key "titles" and a value of a string. Is this correct? Can you show us what data you are parsing from localStorage and what one of the `document.getElementById('elementID').value` look like?

Comment: @Marie the data I'm trying to retrieve is based on user input. So for example when someone visits my page, they input some data such as the title, it will be stored in the variable title. then in localStorage the key would be 'titles' and the value would be 'title'. what I'm trying to do is also make the var title.value getting .pushed into the titles array

Comment: If titles is actually an array of string titles then what you are going to end up with is `var titles = [ {'titles': 'Mrs'}, 'Mr', 'Sr'];` An example of actual data would really help

Answer (score 0):

If your variable name is `title` for example, then you can access it using `window['title']`. This means that if you define an array of your global variable names:

```
const varNames = ['title', 'brief', 'hover', ...]
```

Then you can do a loop like the following

```
for(const name of varNames) {
  const value = window[name]
  // do whatever you want using the variable name and value 
}
```

I hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: Ahh, okay I'll try out your solution. Thank you!

Comment: When I tried it out, it said that const is a reserved word and I couldn't use it this way